# If I put an L298N between a 12V source and a 100W DC fan, what will happen?

Tags: motor-controller, load

The L298N stepper motor controller module has a driving current of 2A ("MAX single bridge", not sure what that means) and a maximum power of 25W. I don't understand what those power limits mean. Could it damage the module if the load exceeds those limits?

I'm not sure how much load the large DC fan draws (**edit:** seems to be 100W), and if I connect it directly to a LiFePO 12V 20AH battery, it depletes the charge quickly and spins at a high speed. If I connect it to a 12V 2A power supply, the fan works, but feebly. I don't have a bench power supply *yet* (but I have ordered one), so to my knowledge I don't have a way of measuring the fan's full potential load demand (but I'd be interested to hear if there is a way, without a variable power supply).

**Edit:** I tried using a multimeter to measure the current, but when I connect it in series, the fan doesn't work at all (I don't understand why; maybe because the multimeter is max 20A, so at 12V that'd only be 240W, which is about 25% of what I guess the fan's load is). My multimeter unfortunately doesn't have a current clamp (perhaps I should get a better multimeter).

If I put the L298N module between a 12V battery and a large fan (**edit:** seems to be 100W), could it burn the module out? If it would burn out, how would you prevent this? A resistor?

**Edit:** I've done some digging on the salvaged DC fan, and figured out from the [wiring diagram](https://f01.justanswer.com/heavy_chevy_396/cb9fb152-e4a4-4c0d-84e0-fefedd5cd530_2013_Fiat_500_1.4L_Eng_VIN_H_Sport_cool_fan_wir.pdf) that it perhaps draws (edit: 8.7A) on a 12V circuit. So, I guess it's a 100W fan and could always try to draw that amount of power? It also seems to come with a 0.8 Ohm resistor attached, but that's not actually connected to anything (the wiring diagram seems to suggest that it is used with the low fan speed relay).

**Edit:** I ordered a 12V 20A power supply (edit: seems to be overkill, as I now realise it's probably a 100W fan instead of 1000W), and plan to use the [0.8 Ohm resistor](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/123602347087?hash=item1cc746244f:g:7EsAAOSw%7EOFeMX0z) that comes with the salvaged fan. I also have a 12V 40A automotive relay that I plan to use (edit: but maybe that's overkill). I hope I can control this relay with a 3.3V IC. Someone please tell me if this is not correct.

Comment: that 25W is pretty much a lie. the 2A are true for *very* generous cooling. Why would you use an L298N? That thing is really obsolete, for good reason: there's very many better H-Bridge ICs that have a far lower resistance when on, and thus, convert far less power to heat and hence can deal with far more current.

Comment: questions such as `will it do ... ?` cannot be answered ... it is like asking `if I cross the street, will I be hit by a vehicle?` ... only questions like `could it ...?` can be answered

Comment: A good strategy of asking questions on SE is to include the relevant information. In your case, the specs of the fan and the schematics of what you are trying to construct.

Comment: _"I don't have a way of measuring the fan's load demand (but I'd be interested to hear if there is a way"_ - You don't have a multimeter?

Comment: When I put my multimeter in series with the fan and the battery, the fan doesn't work. The max amps for the multimeter is 20A, so does this mean that the fan draws more than 20A and the multimeter is preventing the circuit from completing?

Comment: @fraxinus Ok, I've added an edit. That's the best I can do for now with my limited electronics skill and understanding.

Comment: Wow, that much? I am yet to see a 1000W fan running at 12V. It should be able to topple you just with its airstream. It will require finger-thick wires as well. Are you sure it is not 100W ? And... why on earth you want it connected to a stepper motor controller ??? The fans are not stepper motors, it would be pointless?

Comment: Ah, I have seen the diagram. It is a Fiat500 cooling fan, so likely ~100W and not 1000. Still a honest ~8.7 ampere when running and probably as high as 40A when starting. L198N has no application near it.

Comment: Ah, how did you work out 100W? I can't seem to find a datasheet for it, and the fan itself only says 12V on the label (unless I'm reading it wrong). I assumed it was 87A * 12V (as 87A is all over the diagram). I was mislead by an incorrectly labelled fan saying "1000W" in the title, but now I see that most fans are actually 100W.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 298 is not a good choice for this.
If you just want to switch the fan on or off, just use a low side MOSFET with generous Amperage rating.

[image]

This circuit uses IRLB8721 which is nice because it's available in hobbyist places, it's through-hole if you're prototyping this on breadboard, and it has a low Vgs so you can drive it from typical microcontrollers, and it has 30V tolerance (so the Zener might not be needed.) There are many, many other N-channel MOSFETs who have different trade-offs on the amps / drive strength / voltage tolerance spectrum. A parametric search for parts at a place like DigiKey will find many examples of exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the diagram. I have done some research and it seems that the fan is about 1000W (12V 87A). That seems to make sense, as many household fans are also 1000W. I have edited my original question with some more info. Will this circuit work with a 1000W fan?

Comment: Correction: I meant 100W, not 1000W.

Comment: I see that the IRLB8721 handles up to 30V 62A. How about the IRF530N as the circuit is only 8.3A? Or is it pointless because it’s the same price as the IRLB8721? I guess IRF530N is more for high voltage circuits?

Comment: Having a higher amperage rated MOSFET is almost always better, because you will develop lower waste heat and need less cooling. The rating is typically "when connected to a heat sink of size X" and if you don't want to bother with a heat sink, you can use a higher-rated FET for lower load. Look at the Rds at your Vgs to and then use I-squared-R to calculate how much it dissipates.
Yes, there are MOSFETs with higher voltage tolerance. And then at higher voltage, IGBTs.

Comment: And, yes, the IRLB8721 would do fine without a heatsink when driven by a 5V or 3.3V microcontroller and load is 8.7A. If you end up needing higher loads than the device can do, you can generally parallel them pretty easily, BUT watch out for gate charge -- basically, the fatter your MOSFET, the more current it temporarily needs into the gate to switch on/off quickly.
Also, in the diagram above, if your MCU has weak GPIOs, you'll want a 100-400 Ohm resistor on the "control" gate line, to avoid overloading the GPIO when switching. Ohm's law and a datasheet will help here.

Comment: Exceptionally helpful info, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand what those power limits mean; will it damage the
> module if the load exceeds those limits?

[image]
Source: [L298N datasheet](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/82/cc/3f/39/0a/29/4d/f0/CD00000240.pdf/files/CD00000240.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000240.pdf)

The datasheet lists three limits of \$I_o\$, it depends on how much time you have the output turned on. \$I_o\$ generates heat through the transistros in the H-bridge of the L298N, heat will damage the part. If the current \$I_o\$ is continuous, then the limit is 2A. If \$I_o\$ is pulsed (less than 10ms) and less than an 80% duty cycle, then the L298 \$I_o\$ can handle 2.5A. If less than 100us it can handle 3A

> but if I connect it directly to the battery.

Don't connect it directly to the battery, the battery is unregulated (with a voltage potentially more than 14V) , you need a 12V regulator or DC DC regulator between the battery and load.

If you want to measure the current of the fan, use a meter in current mode between fan and power supply (series).

Comment: I don't think a regulator is needed for something like a fan. Most motors have generous tolerance for actual voltage, as long as you don't burn them out. Even "car electronics" that's nominally 12V almost always runs at 13.6 Volts, which is a charged lead-acid battery, or even higher while charging. A fully charged LeFePO4 battery is 14.4 Volts, but very quickly decays to 14V or less with power draw.

Comment: Funny you should mention car electronics. It's the radiator fan from a Fiat 500. I tried to find the fan motor specs but my Google-fu is weak when it comes to electronics.

Comment: @JonWatte If you want the same current through a load, then you'd better regulate the voltage. 14V= fan rpm too high. 12V = fan the same as the 2A supply (assuming that the voltage isn't being pulled down by the load).

Comment: After some research, it seems that the fan is about 1000W (12V 87A). I have edited my original question with some more info.

Comment: From my edited question: "I tried using a multimeter to measure the current, but when I connect it in series, the fan doesn't work at all (I don't understand why; maybe because the multimeter is max 20A, so at 12V that'd only be 240W, which is about 25% of what I guess the fan's load is). My multimeter unfortunately doesn't have a current clamp (perhaps I should get a better multimeter)."

Comment: Usually you have to move one of the leads

Comment: I don't understand about moving one of the leads. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Also, correction: I realised it's actually 100W, not 1000W. So, it'll probably draw only 8.7A (not 87A). Therefore my 20A multimeter should be able to read the amps. I'm totally confused.

Comment: What meter do you have?